# Cannot initialize return object of type 'int' with an lvalue of type 'int (int, int)'

Tags: c++, c++11

This is a homework assignment for school. I don't understand the error that is arising from my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// v--we are only allowed to change code within these lines--v
int myMin(int num1, int num2)
{
    min(num1, num2);
    return myMin;
}
// ^--the rest of the code must remain as written--^

int main()
{
    cout << myMin(4, 8) << endl;
    cout << myMin(6, 3) << endl;
    cout << myMin(-2, -4) << endl;
}
```

We are to write:

```
int myMin(int num1, int num2)
```

To display the correct lowest number. I keep receiving the error:

> cannot initialize return object of type 'int' with an lvalue of type 'int (int, int)'.

Comment: `return myMin`?

Comment: While people on StackOverflow want to help, it's important that you avoid the practice of "typing in random things and hoping they work"!  Please provide justification in your questions of why you thought what you wrote *would* have worked--and if you look for that justification but all you have is "I just made it up", then rethink/rewrite your question without the made-up bit.

Comment: Is your comment directed at me or the person who left the comment on my question? @HostileFork

Comment: @Matt The comment is for you.  Calling `min(num1, num2);`, not saving the result anywhere, and then writing `return myMin;` has no precedent in any tutorial I can think of.  As far as I can tell, you made it up.  If you didn't--please share the source so we can correct it.

Comment: @Matt Also, if this is an assignment, it may be that rather than delegate to the standard library min() function...you're being asked to actually do comparisons yourself.  You might want to review what the rules were *(e.g. "without using any standard library templates/functions...")*

Comment: I'm am all for constructive criticism and love to learn and grow, however, nothing about your original post was constructive. It was just blatantly rude and disrespectful. I don't know much about code, this website, or how to articulate my thoughts in this environment (which apparently was evident in my original post) and you did nothing but make accusations and assumptions. Had you of said "hey, don't do x, y, and z and I edited your post so you have a good example for the next time you post" I would have been apologetic and thankful but the way you came at me is not helpful.

Comment: @Matt It's difficult for *any* criticism to sound constructive (ears are always sensitive), but I assure you mine is meant as such.  Your question was downvoted (not by me) and closed by 4 other voters as being off topic and inappropriate for the site.  I'm giving you an explanation as to why, and some advice--including the advice I gave about checking your question to see if delegating to min() is what the assignment intended.  Good luck, and be aware that getting the most out of StackOverflow means listening to good advice when people take the time to give it.

Comment: I can respect that, however, you even saying the phrase "delegating to min()" isn't even a phrase uttered by my professor. To experienced people, this question may seem benign but i really tried and had no idea the correlation between the values as @StephanLechner explained it. Our conversation may be off-topic but i don't feel the question is and as there is no private place to have a conversation such as this, i'm left conversating via comments since i don't even have enough StackOverflow respect to use the chatrooms.

Comment: @Matt What I was emphasizing is that it is not the level of *expertise* of the question that can get people in trouble...rather when it seems what's being submitted is random typing.  The best way to avoid being perceived that way is to explain your thinking along with the code.  If you can't explain the thinking behind every line you are posting, then that's a sign you should take a step back.  Implementing one's own min would be e.g. `if (num1 < num2) return num1; else return num2;` -- this may be what you are being asked for, vs just calling an already-written min() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write ...

```
return min(num1, num2);
```

instead of

```
return myMin;
```

Name `myMin` is the name of your function, and returning `myMin` then would mean that you return a pointer to your function, i.e. a function type `int(int,int)` instead of an `int`-value.

Comment: This worked, but please see below for knowledge for myself.

edit 3: thank you, in my haste, I failed to see your full breakdown at the bottom of your post. That makes sense, thank you for breaking it all down!

Comment: You have to return a value of the type indicated by the function, int in this case.  That's why this works.